# Cast integer to enum type with Flags attribute

Tags: enums, casting, f#, type-conversion, flags

I have an enum type with the flags attribute:

```ml
[<Flags>]
type StatusWord =
    | DATAPROCESS       = 0b0000000001
    | ERRORPRESENT      = 0b0000000010
    | CHECKSUMERROR     = 0b0000000100
    | PACKETSIZEERROR   = 0b0000001000
    | TIMEOUT           = 0b0000010000
    | DONOTRETRY        = 0b1000000000
```

and during some data initialization, I have a `uint16` value I want to convert to the enum's type, `StatusWord`, so I can compare it's properties:

```ml
let value: uint16 = 0b1000001001us
let flags: StatusWord = StatusWord value
```

but, as you might be able to guess, this code doesn't compile; the conversion isn't available. Likewise, I also can't do explicit casts, eg. `value :> StatusWord` or `value :?> StatusWord`. This is a simple task in C#, so I'm having trouble figuring out why I can't do it in F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, two things you have to worry about. One (which I think you already realize) is that your underlying enum type is int32, and your value is uint16, so a conversion will need to happen somewhere. Two, you have to construct the enum type.

StatusWord looks like a constructor (similar to a union case member), but it's not. So here are two ways to do it with your uint16 value, and a third way to do it which is much better for readability, if you can do it that way.

```
let value = 0b1000001001us

// use F# enum operator
let flags1 = enum<StatusWord> (int value)

// use static Enum class
let flags2 = Enum.Parse(typeof<StatusWord>, string value) :?> StatusWord

// do bitwise stuff, of course now the compiler knows what you're doing
let flags3 = StatusWord.DATAPROCESS ||| StatusWord.PACKETSIZEERROR ||| StatusWord.DONOTRETRY
```

Because there are multiple ways, I had to refresh my memory, which I did at

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/enum-types/

which is highly recommended reading (that article and the rest of that blog - it's how many people learn F#).

Comment: This worked initially, while my enum was of type int32. For a while, I left it like that. But recently, I've come to the point where I'd like to make the enum itself a byte type, and translated it as such. But now none of these solutions work any longer. The first one, using the F# enum operator, throws an error, saying it can't convert from int32 to byte. The second one tells me that static coercion is unnecessary, since the enum has no proper subtypes. And unfortunately, the third one is not possible in my current situation.

Comment: Nevermind, it actually works. I was adding an unnecessary coercion to the end.

Answer (score 4):

To convert a numerical value to an enum in F#, you can use the built-in `LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue` function.

```
let flags: StatusWord = LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue value
```

In your example, this does not actually work, because the type of `value` is `uint16`, but the underlying type of the enum is `int` (because the values do not have the `us` suffix). To get that to work, you'll need to either convert `uint32` to `int`, or change the definition of your enum. The following works perfectly:

```
[<Flags>]
type StatusWord =
    | DATAPROCESS       = 0b0000000001us
    | ERRORPRESENT      = 0b0000000010us
    | CHECKSUMERROR     = 0b0000000100us
    | PACKETSIZEERROR   = 0b0000001000us
    | TIMEOUT           = 0b0000010000us
    | DONOTRETRY        = 0b1000000000us

let value: uint16 = 0b1000001001us
let flags: StatusWord = LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue value
```

**EDIT:** Jim's answer mentions the `enum` function. For some reason (I'm not sure why!) this only works with `int32` arguments, so using `EnumOfValue` is probably better if you want to keep the base type of your enum as `uint16`. If you wanted to keep that as `int32`, then `enum` is much nicer option!

Comment: I knew someone would post yet another way!

Comment: @JimFoye I was just about to delete my answer, because yours with `enum` was better, but then I noticed that `enum` only works on integers. That is really odd - I have no idea why it isn't just an alias for `EnumOfValue`! I guess you learn something new every day :-)